# php mysql table videos time update

Tags: php

hello I have videos table and in this table I have a column named "video_update". When I open the related video page, the update process is done. I want the update to be done every 30 minutes. I do not want the page to be updated every time I log in. I want it to be done every 30 minutes. but I don't know how to do it because I have very little php knowledge. can you help with an example

For example: When I click "video?id=3", if the update time in the database is done before 30 minutes, it will not be updated. If it's more than 30 minutes, let the update be updated.

```
$data['page_content'] = json_encode($result[0]['items'][0]);
$data['page_update'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$id = $service_['page_id'];

if ($control) {
    YoutubeApi::VideoUpdate($id, $data);
}

class YoutubeApi
{
    public static function VideoUpdate($id, $data)
    {

        global $db;
        return $query = $db->update('pages')
            ->where('page_id', $id)
            ->set($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I want the update to be done every 30 minutes"...use a Cron job to run an update script. (Or a Scheduled Task, if you're using Windows). It's not really a PHP problem, it's just that you need to know how to run a program automatically on your system. And now you know - or at least you know what you need to investigate.

Comment: You can create a simple php script that does the "update process" and then run this script with a [crontab](https://crontab.guru/)

Comment: you misunderstood me. For example: When I click "video?id=3", if the update time in the database is done before 30 minutes, it will not be updated. If it's more than 30 minutes, let the update be updated.

Comment: Is it Laravel Framework?

Answer (score 0):

You should to add next condition to your update query:

`TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(now(), updated_at))/60 > 30`

- `TIMEDIFF` calculate time between updated time and now
- `TIME_TO_SEC` convert result into seconds
- Divide 60 to get time in minutes

So your query will be like this:

```
update videos 
set updated_at = now() 
where id = 3 and TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(now(), updated_at))/60 > 30;
```

[You can try it here, at PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=7cae0fee50188f6499e53d6cc0ef0986&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80)

Also you can use SQL function `TIMESTAMPDIFF`

```
update videos 
set updated_at = now() 
where id = 1 and TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, updated_at, now()) > 30;
```

For implement it in Eloquent query builder use next:

```
$query = $db->update('pages')
            ->where('page_id', $id)
            ->whereRaw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, updated_at, now()) > 30')
            ->set($data);
```

Comment: I updated the question, but I did not understand how to do what you said.

Comment: no laravel i am using php. You can give an example as basicdb but pdo.